# Java - Observer/Observable in a distributed application?

Tags: java, sockets, observer-pattern

I want to implement the observer pattern in a distributed application.
i.e. something happens with the database in a instance of an application, and a notification should be sent to the other instance, through a socket, such that the second one will reload the data from the db. 
Should i use:

a) the observer/observable classes from java

b) an event-based approach, something like, adding an Event listener when pressing a button and then send the notification through a socket

c)any other ideas/options

I would like to know which is the most optimal approach

P.S. I'm working at a swing application which connects to a MySQL db. Everything is on localhost (is not for production purposes).

Comment: What is your platform? Are you using an application server? Can you use a JMS server...?

Comment: If the observer and the observable are in two different JVMs, and communicate through sockets, how do you plan to add an observer to an observable? The optimal approach would be to use something like a JMS topic.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh just added some more details (the P.S. paragraph)

Comment: If you use basic Sockets, be sure to queue each message so that they get read in order.  Otherwise a thread might complete reading the 2nd message before it completes the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're tied to the Socket route, I'd recommend creating another Java App to act as a server and broker to manage the connection traffic.  Basically, have that App create a ServerSocket and bind to a port.  Then all your existing JVM instances can make a client connection to it.  Basically a mini-client-server architecture.  When the server receives notifications of events from any client, it can re-broadcast the message to every other client.